# qInstallMsgHandler error while registering log function in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4

I am designing Qt log window, So I am using qInstallMsgHandler() function to log all the debug, critical & warning messages on to QTableWidget (in below code I have not implemented yet). I did as below

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qInstallMsgHandler(MainWindow::logMessage);
    //qInstallMsgHandler(&MainWindow::logMessage);  //I tried this also

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    qDebug()    << "info message";
    qWarning()  << "warning message";
    qCritical() << "critical message";
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**MainWindow:**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :QMainWindow(parent),ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::logMessage(QtMsgType type, const char *msg)
{
    switch (type) {
    case QtDebugMsg:
        fprintf(stderr, "Debug: %s\n", msg);
        break;
    case QtWarningMsg:
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: %s\n", msg);
        break;
    case QtCriticalMsg:
        fprintf(stderr, "Critical: %s\n", msg);
        break;
    case QtFatalMsg:
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal: %s\n", msg);
        abort();
    }
}
```

When I compile this code, I am getting below error

```
main.cpp:27: error: cannot convert 'void (MainWindow::*)(QtMsgType, const char*)' to 'QtMsgHandler {aka void (*)(QtMsgType, const char*)}' for argument '1' to 'void (* qInstallMsgHandler(QtMsgHandler))(QtMsgType, const char*)'
     qInstallMsgHandler(MainWindow::logMessage);
```

Please let me know if any one had faced this issue.

Note : If I changed void MainWindow::logMessage(QtMsgType type, const char *msg); this function to static function this is working fine.

(But if this function is static, I can not create QTableWidgetItem and add them to tableWidget so I want this function to be non static).

I am using Qt4.8.6 on Windows7

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: That's exactly the problem -- you must use a free function there, not a member function. An option would be using `std::bind` to capture the instance, but you then need to move your `qInstallMsgHandler` call after the `MainWindow` creation. Another one is making your `MainWindow` instance a true singleton, i.e. accessible via `MainWindow::instance()` or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a static variable MainWindow in MainWindow which will allow you to access the instance of the MainWindow from a static function e.g.

```
static MainWindow *_this;
```

set this Variable in the constructor:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
   _this = this;
}
```

create a static function with the same signature to be registered in `qInstallMsgHandler`. This function will do only the redirection to the not-static function using the static _this:

```
static void logMessageHandle(QtMsgType type, const char *msg)
{
   if(_this)
      _this->logMessage(type,msg);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Or use a C++11 lambda, which can capture the MainWindow ptr.